# Range of $(\tan^{-1}x)^3+(\cot^{-1}x)^3$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

> Finding range of function
> $$\ \ f(x)=(\tan^{-1}(x))^3+(\cot^{-1}(x))^3$$

I am trying to solve above using Inequality

We know that $\tan^{-1}(x),\cot^{-1}(x)$ is defined for $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$

Using Inequality

$\displaystyle \frac{(\tan^{-1}(x))^3+(\cot^{-1}(x))^3}{2}\geq \bigg(\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)+\cot^{-1}(x)}{2}\bigg)^3=\frac{\pi^3}{64}$

So we have $\displaystyle \bigg(\tan^{-1}(x)\bigg)^3+\bigg(\cot^{-1}(x)\bigg)^3 \geq \frac{\pi^3}{32}$

Equality hold when $\displaystyle x=1$

Also at $\displaystyle f(-\infty)= -\frac{\pi^3}{8}$

Also at $\displaystyle f(\infty)=\frac{\pi^3}{8}$

So range of function as $\displaystyle \bigg[\frac{\pi^3}{32},\frac{\pi^3}{8}\bigg)$

But in wolframalpha , it shows answer as $\displaystyle \bigg(-\frac{\pi^3}{8},-\frac{\pi^3}{32}\bigg]\cup \bigg[\frac{\pi^3}{32},\frac{\pi^3}{8}\bigg)$

Please have a look on that problem, Thanks

Comment: Wolfram Alpha and Desmos use different definitions of $\cot^{-1}(x),x<0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us note that for $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$, range of $\tan^{-1}x$ is $\Big( \dfrac{-\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2} \Big)$ and that of $\cot^{-1}x$ is $(0,\pi)$. Also $\tan^{-1}x + \cot^{-1}x = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Setting $\tan^{-1}x=y$,
$$f(y) = y^3 + \Big( \frac{\pi}{2} - y \Big)^3 = \frac{\pi^3}{8} + \frac{3\pi}{2}\Big(y^2 - \frac{\pi}{2}y \Big)$$
On completing the square,
$$f(y) = \frac{\pi^3}{32} + \frac{3\pi}{2}\Big( y - \frac{\pi}{4}\Big)^2 $$
Graph of $f(y)$ is an upward opening parabola with vertex at $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. Since $y \in \Big( \dfrac{-\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2} \Big)$ and $f(y)$ is continuous, it attains minima at $\Big( \dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{\pi^3}{32} \Big)$. For $y \rightarrow \Big( \dfrac{-\pi}{2} \Big)^+$, maximum value of $f(y)$ approaches $\dfrac{7\pi^3}{8}$.

Thus range of $f(x)$ is $\Big[\dfrac{\pi^3}{32},\dfrac{7\pi^3}{8} \Big)$. It is never negative.

[image]

---

Note that $f(-\infty) = \Big(\dfrac{-\pi}{2}\Big)^3 + (\pi)^3 = \dfrac{7\pi^3}{8}$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses the definitions Wolfram Alpha uses. (The range of $\cot^{-1}x$ is $(-\frac {\pi}2,0)\cup (0,\frac{\pi}2]$.)

I'm going to have a look on your try.

> $\displaystyle \frac{(\tan^{-1}(x))^3+(\cot^{-1}(x))^3}{2}\geq \bigg(\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)+\cot^{-1}(x)}{2}\bigg)^3=\frac{\pi^3}{64}$

I think that for $x\lt 0$, this does not hold.

Note that we have
$$\frac{(\tan^{-1}x)^3+(\cot^{-1}x)^3}{2}-\bigg(\frac{\tan^{-1}x+\cot^{-1}x}{2}\bigg)^3=\frac 38(\tan^{-1}x + \cot^{-1}x)\bigg(\tan^{-1}x -\cot^{-1}x\bigg)^2\tag1$$

For $x\lt 0$, we have $\tan^{-1}x + \cot^{-1}x=\color{red}-\frac{\pi}{2}$, so
$$\frac{\tan^{-1}x)^3+(\cot^{-1}x)^3}{2}\color{red}{\le}\bigg(\frac{\tan^{-1}x+\cot^{-1}x}{2}\bigg)^3\color{red}{\le -\frac{\pi^3}{64}}$$

I think that it should be better to add a proof that $y$ satisfying $y\gt\frac{\pi^3}{8}$ are not included in the range. (That you have $f(\infty)=\frac{\pi^3}{8}$ does not necessarily imply that the range is smaller than $\frac{\pi^3}{8}$.)

To find the range of $f(x)$ rigorously, you can use $(1)$.

Since $$\tan^{-1}x -\cot^{-1}x=\begin{cases}\tan^{-1}-(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}x)&\text{if $x\ge 0$}\\
\tan^{-1}x-(-\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}x)&\text{if $x\lt 0$}\end{cases}$$
you'll see that $f(x)$ can be expressed as a quadratic function on $\tan^{-1}x$. (MyMolecules has already pointed this out.)

We can write
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{3\pi}{2}\bigg(\tan^{-1}x-\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg)^2+\frac{\pi^3}{32}&\text{if $x\ge 0$}
\\-\frac{3\pi}{2}\bigg(\tan^{-1}x+\frac{\pi}{4}\bigg)^2-\frac{\pi^3}{32}&\text{if $x\lt 0$}\end{cases}$$

I think from here, you can see that the range of $f(x)$ is
$$\color{red}{\bigg(-\frac{\pi^3}{8},-\frac{\pi^3}{32}\bigg]\cup \bigg[\frac{\pi^3}{32},\frac{\pi^3}{8}\bigg]}$$
(Note that $f(0)=\frac{\pi^3}{8}$ is included in the range.)